# Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace when using image_picker flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, imagepicker

when im using image_picker in flutter web
getting issue 'Error: Unsupported operation: *Namespace
at Object.throw* [as throw] (http://localhost:56308/dart_sdk.js:5334:11)
at Function.get _namespace [as _namespace] (http://localhost:56308/dart_sdk.js:55299:17)
at io._File.new.lengthSync (http://localhost:56308/dart_sdk.js:53158:59)'

This is working fine in android on image selection window open in and image is successfully previewed
but not working in flutter web
In web case image selection window open but image not getting.

This is my image picker code...

final picker = ImagePicker();
var imag = await picker.getImage(source: oursource);

```
var imageFile = File(imag.path);
```

Answer (score 7):

use this:

```
kIsWeb
? Image.network(selectedImage.path)
: Image.file(File(selectedImage.path)),
```

i hope working (its too late ;)  )

Comment: Loved it man! Still working 2024!

Comment: @Hamza Glad to hear it <3

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using File from 'dart:io' use html.File
example:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;

var imageFile = html.File(image.path.codeUnits, image.path);
```

To get the path, use *imageFile.name*.

This works for me.